# Should I create a folder for release branches in SVN?

Tags: svn

I would like to separate release branches from feature branches by puting them in a release folder. I know best practices with svn is to have your root folder structure like this:

```
\trunk
\branches
    \feature-a
    \feature-b
    \...
\tags
    \1.0 
    \...
```

My understanding of svn is that the trunk/branches/tags folders carry no special meaning to svn. Would I run into any issues by adding a release folder to the root of the project and putting all my release branches in that folder?

```
\trunk
\branches
    \feature-a
    \feature-b
    \...
\releases
    \release-a
    \...
\tags
    \1.0 
    \...
```

Creating a new release branch would look like this:

```
svn copy http://project/trunk http://project/releases/release-b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you structure your repository is up to you.  If you need to have branch categories/folders/etc, so be it.  Once you decide on the structure you want/need, you then create a process to handle it.  The underlying Subversion commands will not change of course.

Answer (score 1):

It would work fine, although personally, I don't like it much. "Releases" sounds like a kind of tag (fixed point) when you mean it to be a kind of branch (evolving towards a release.)

Comment: Well, I can see a release branch where you branch a release to do bug fix development or something.  The verbiage might be a little confusing of course.  ;)

Comment: @Jeremy -- I think you have me backwards. Yes, a release branch *is* supposed to be like a branch where you do bug fixes and stuff; when you do an actual release, you make a tag from the branch. I'm just saying that if I saw a directory in the repository called "releases", I'd be expecting it to contain those release *tags*, not release *branches*. Maybe that's just me, though.

Comment: We're in agreement that the verbiage is confusing/vague.

Comment: Release branches are long term branches that are created when work for a release is done. So release branches are kind of a fixed point although some work will be done in them. We will tag from the release branches. Feature branches are rarely used because most of the work is done in the trunk. But every now and then a large feature comes down the pipe that warrants a branch.

Answer (score 1):

What is your workflow going to look like? At that point either the tags directory becomes irrelevant, and you might as well rename "tags" to "releases", or the trunk becomes irrelevant because all development is going on in either release or feature branches.

My suggestion would be to simply rename the "tags" folder as "releases".

Answer (score 0):

I do this and other things similar.  Same workflow different paths.  The problem is solved is clutter.  When you have, for example, builds being tagged, and task branches ongoing the folders can be a bit cluttered.  I usually keep a little svn sandbox locally so that i can try out the workflow to make sure i haven't messed up anything.

On some projects I use a separate repository for releases, and an svn:external as a hand-off.  in this sense it is a more of a 'delivery' hand-off to another group.  development workflows and operations roll-out workflows can differ.  this separated the two.

on the project i am setting up now - probably going to call it maint or support just to spice things up. :)